# I can't run this query with MERGE in Teradata

Tags: teradata

This query worked perfectly until the moment I went in for vacations, now itdoes not run anymore and does not merge, dont know what it can be

```
MERGE INTO STG_FATO_MACRO_GESTAO AS FAT
USING(SELECT DISTINCT
            COD_EMPRESA
            ,FUN.MATRICULA AS FUN_MAT
            ,APR.MATRICULA AS APR_MAT
            ,FUN.CPF AS FUN_CPF
            ,APR.CPF AS APR_CPF
            ,APR.DAT_DESLIGAMENTO
            ,YEAR(APR.DAT_DESLIGAMENTO)*100+MONTH(APR.DAT_DESLIGAMENTO) AS DESL
            ,FUN.DATA_ADMISSAO
            ,YEAR(FUN.DATA_ADMISSAO)*100+MONTH(FUN.DATA_ADMISSAO) AS ADM
            , CASE WHEN YEAR(APR.DAT_DESLIGAMENTO)*100+MONTH(APR.DAT_DESLIGAMENTO) <= YEAR(FUN.DATA_ADMISSAO)*100+MONTH(FUN.DATA_ADMISSAO) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ADMITIDO
            ,CASE WHEN FUN.DATA_ADMISSAO <= (APR.DAT_DESLIGAMENTO + INTERVAL '90' DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS APR_90
            
            FROM (SELECT CPF,DATA_ADMISSAO, MATRICULA, COD_EMPRESA FROM DIM_FUNCIONARIO
                    WHERE PROFISSAO NOT LIKE '%APRENDIZ%') AS FUN
                INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                CPF,DAT_DESLIGAMENTO,MATRICULA 
                            FROM HST_APRENDIZ
                            WHERE FLAG_FECHAMENTO = 2
                                AND DAT_DESLIGAMENTO  IS NOT NULL)  AS APR
                ON FUN.CPF = APR.CPF) AS APR_90
                
ON FAT.COD_EMPRESA = APR_90.COD_EMPRESA
AND FAT.MATRICULA = APR_90.FUN_MAT
AND APR_90.APR_90 = 1
AND APR_90.ADMITIDO = 1

     WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE SET APRENDIZ_EFETIVADO_90 = 1
;
```

when running this query returns me this error:

"The search condition must fully specify the Target table primary index and partition column(s) and expression must match INSERT specification primary index and partition column(s). "

Comment: You have tagged your question [tag:mysql], but you can't be using MySQL, because [MySQL doesn't support the `MERGE` statement](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9018). Please tag your question correctly. It's a good idea to do so, because it will attract the attention of users who are best able to answer your question!

Comment: sorry, as almost all mysql syntaxes work on teradata I thought it would be the same thing, i've changed

Comment: If it worked before the target table's Primary Index or partitioning changed